# Mayor cercano de un numero dado

Tags: c++, array

Quiero hacer una función que me de el mayor numero cercano de un numero dado dentro de un arreglo, también hice el de mayor numero lejano, esta función si me funciona (o se creo). Adjunto mi código de las dos funciones.
Mi código está en c++.

```
int mayorlejano(int A[],int x,int n)
{int i,val,dif=0; 
    for(i=0;i<n; i++)
    { if(A[i]>x)
        {
            if(A[i]-x>dif)
            {
                val=A[i];
                dif=A[i]-x;
            }
        }
       
    }
    return val;
}
int mayorcercano(int A[],int x,int n)
{int i,val,dif; 
    for(i=1;i<n; i++)
    {val=A[0]; dif=A[0]-x;
        if(A[i]>x)
        {
            if(A[i]-x<dif)
            {
                val=A[i];
                dif=A[i]-x;
            }
        }
       
    }
    return val;
}
```

También en otro post encontré este código que esta en Java pero no funciona, creo que es porque posicionNumeroMasCercano nunca cambia y se queda en 0 siempre. Este es el codigo:

```
public static int masCercano(int[] numeros, int num) { 
  int menorDistanciaActual = Math.abs(num - numeros[0]); // Aca guardas la resta
  int posicionNumeroMasCercano = 0; // Si viene un array con un elemento, es el [0]

  // Empezas en 1, porque ya sabes que el 0 es el mas cercano hasta ahora.
  for (int i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    int distanciaEntreNumeros = Math.abs(num - numeros[i]);

    if (distanciaEntreNumeros < menorDistanciaActual) {
      menorDistanciaActual = distanciaEntreNumeros;
      posicionNumeroMasCercano = i;
    }
  }

  return numeros[posicionNumeroMasCercano];
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es el número cercano y el número lejano?

Comment: Por ejemplo si tengo un array de 5 elementos: {15,  29, 84, 93, 47} e introduzco un número, digamos 20 el mayor cercano es 29 y el mayor lejano es 93. En pocas palabras la menor diferencia y mayor diferencia

Answer (score 0):

Si un requisito es que el número sea **mayor** entonces no puedes aplicar `Math.abs`  porque si lo haces entonces los números más pequeños te arrojarán distancias positivas ... indistinguibles de las distancias de los números más grandes.

Para coger el mayor cercano debes quedarte con aquél número que, dándote una distancia positiva, su valor es el más pequeño:

```
int menorDistancia = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int numeroMasCercano = -1;

for (int numeroActual : numeros) {
    int distancia = numeroActual - num;
    if (distancia > 0 && distancia < menorDistancia) {
        menorDistancia = distancia;
        numeroMasCercano = numeroActual;
    }
}

return numeroMasCercano;
```

Comment: Porque número más cercano se inicializa en -1? Y no hay otra forma de comparar la diferencia sin tener que usar el valor maximo?

Comment: @user20609943 dado que todos los númerosson positivos, habría valido el 0 o cualquier otro negativo. Usar un valor no válido permite detectar el caso de que no exista un número que cumpla los requisitos

Comment: En cuanto a la distancia... al inicializarla con el entero más alto posible, cualquier distancia válida dará un resultado menor, luego dicho valor se registrará sin tener que hacer tratamientos especiales en el algoritmo